# Karate Removing different parts of JSON

Tags: json, karate

Please find below my formatted JSON Payload Dis.json

```
{
  "id": "",
  "discount_type": "COUPON",
  "name": "Festive Treebo discount",
  "code": "ABCDE",
  "description": "50% off discount",
  "is_visible": true,
  "implementation_logic": "EXPLICIT",
  "is_auto_applicable": true,
  "validity_start": "2018-09-30T18:30:00.000Z",
  "validity_end": "2018-10-30T18:30:00.000Z",
  "total_inventory": 100,
  "incentive_value_type": "PERCENTAGE",
  "incentive_apply_on": "TRANSACTION_PRICE",
  "incentive_value": 20,
  "applicable_on": "PRE_TAX",
  "max_incentive_value": 500,
  "rules": {
    "AND": [
      {
        "RULE": {
          "operator": "EQ",
          "attribute_name": "PAYMODE",
          "attribute_value": "PREPAID",
          "attribute_value_type": "STRING",
          "status": "ACTIVE"
        }
      },
      {
        "OR": [
          {
            "AND": [
              {
                "RULE": {
                  "operator": "EQ",
                  "attribute_name": "CHANNEL",
                  "attribute_value": "direct",
                  "attribute_value_type": "CSV_ARRAY",
                  "status": "ACTIVE"
                }
              },
              {
                "RULE": {
                  "operator": "IN",
                  "attribute_name": "SUB_CHANNEL",
                  "attribute_value": "trivago",
                  "attribute_value_type": "CSV_ARRAY",
                  "status": "ACTIVE"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "AND": [
              {
                "RULE": {
                  "operator": "EQ",
                  "attribute_name": "CHANNEL",
                  "attribute_value": "assisted-sales",
                  "attribute_value_type": "CSV_ARRAY",
                  "status": "ACTIVE"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "RULE": {
          "operator": "IN",
          "attribute_name": "BLACKOUT_DATES",
          "attribute_value": "16 Oct 2018",
          "attribute_value_type": "CSV_ARRAY",
          "status": "ACTIVE"
        }
      },
      {
        "OR": [
          {
            "RULE": {
              "operator": "IN",
              "attribute_name": "HOTEL_ID",
              "attribute_value": "0048880",
              "attribute_value_type": "CSV_ARRAY",
              "status": "ACTIVE"
            }
          },
          {
            "RULE": {
              "operator": "IN",
              "attribute_name": "CITY",
              "attribute_value": "105",
              "attribute_value_type": "CSV_ARRAY",
              "status": "ACTIVE"
            }
          },
          {
            "RULE": {
              "operator": "IN",
              "attribute_name": "LOCALITY",
              "attribute_value": "2",
              "attribute_value_type": "CSV_ARRAY",
              "status": "ACTIVE"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "RULE": {
          "operator": "IN",
          "attribute_name": "DEVICE",
          "attribute_value": "direct-website",
          "attribute_value_type": "CSV_ARRAY",
          "status": "ACTIVE"
        }
      },
      {
        "RULE": {
          "operator": "EQUALS_GT",
          "attribute_name": "LENGTH_OF_STAY",
          "attribute_value": "3",
          "attribute_value_type": "INTEGER",
          "status": "ACTIVE"
        }
      },
      {
        "RULE": {
          "operator": "EQUALS_GT",
          "attribute_name": "TRANSACTION_VALUE",
          "attribute_value": "1000",
          "attribute_value_type": "INTEGER",
          "status": "ACTIVE"
        }
      },
      {
        "AND": [
          {
            "RULE": {
              "operator": "IN",
              "attribute_name": "UTM_SOURCE",
              "attribute_value": "Paytm",
              "attribute_value_type": "CSV_ARRAY",
              "status": "ACTIVE"
            }
          },
          {
            "RULE": {
              "operator": "IN",
              "attribute_name": "UTM_MEDIUM",
              "attribute_value": "media",
              "attribute_value_type": "CSV_ARRAY",
              "status": "ACTIVE"
            }
          },
          {
            "RULE": {
              "operator": "IN",
              "attribute_name": "UTM_CAMPAIGN",
              "attribute_value": "new year, holi",
              "attribute_value_type": "CSV_ARRAY",
              "status": "ACTIVE"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "RULE": {
          "operator": "EQ",
          "attribute_name": "ABW",
          "attribute_value": "10",
          "attribute_value_type": "INTEGER",
          "status": "ACTIVE"
        }
      },
      {
        "RULE": {
          "operator": "EQUALS_GT",
          "attribute_name": "CHECKIN",
          "attribute_value": "01 Oct 2018",
          "attribute_value_type": "DATE",
          "status": "ACTIVE"
        }
      },
      {
        "RULE": {
          "operator": "EQUALS_LT",
          "attribute_name": "CHECKOUT",
          "attribute_value": "16 Nov 2018",
          "attribute_value_type": "DATE",
          "status": "ACTIVE"
        }
      },
      {
        "RULE": {
          "operator": "IN",
          "attribute_name": "USER_COHORT",
          "attribute_value": "LOYALITY_USER",
          "attribute_value_type": "CSV_ARRAY",
          "status": "ACTIVE"
        }
      },
      {
        "RULE": {
          "operator": "EQUALS_LT",
          "attribute_name": "INVENTORY_CAP",
          "attribute_value": "20",
          "attribute_value_type": "INTEGER",
          "status": "ACTIVE"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "created_by": "abcd@treebohotels.com",
  "success_message": "Coupon applied successfully",
  "error_message": "Coupon not applicable"
}
```

Now here is my feature file code which loads the json files and tries to trim only the json I want

```
Scenario: Json formatting
* def discountInput = read('Dis.json')
* remove discountInput.rules.AND[0]
* remove discountInput.rules.AND[2]
* remove discountInput.rules.AND[3]
* remove discountInput.rules.AND[4]
* remove discountInput.rules.AND[5]
* remove discountInput.rules.AND[6]
* remove discountInput.rules.AND[7]
* remove discountInput.rules.AND[8]
* remove discountInput.rules.AND[9]
* remove discountInput.rules.AND[10]
* remove discountInput.rules.AND[11]
* remove discountInput.rules.AND[12]
* print discountInput
```

When I print this only AND[0] gets removed , But I want to remove everything except AND[1] , How can I do this in karate ?

And also is there a better way than I am doing it currently ?

Comment: I tried * remove discountInput.rules.AND[0],discountInput.rules.AND[1],discountInput.rules.AND[2] ...... but it did not work

Comment: I tried * remove discountInput.rules.AND[0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9..] it did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick Answer:

```
Scenario: Json formatting 
    * def discountInput = read('Dis.json') 
    * def andNode = discountInput.rules.AND[1]
    * remove discountInput.rules
    * set discountInput.rules[0] = andNode
```

This might not be a good solution i was just trying to reduce your line of code

**Edit:**

Here comes one more answer,

Instead of trying to remove data you can filter your json based on a condition provided to karate.filter

```
Scenario: json filter 
    * def discountInput = read('Dis.json') 
    * def filterCondition = function(x) { if(x.RULE){ return true;}} 
    * def allAND = $discountInput.rules.AND[*]
    * set discountInput.rules = karate.filter(allAND, filterCondition)
```

for all the data that matches your condition will be returned as json array from the filter function

from the above example whichever AND node has a RULE will be returned

You can also use any of the above answer with `Scenario Outline:`, and having the index/ filter condition passed from your `Examples:`

Comment: thanks ! I personally think it may be much easier to create the JSON by hand using JS ! I am busy now but try something like `* if (condition) rules.AND[i] = { blah: '1' }`

Comment: peter, remove doest support table as set used to right?

Comment: yeah no table for remove. this may be where `karate.filter()` can help

Comment: Payload will remain the same , only the rules will change(some rules will be removed from the payload in each scenario) so I thought to implement this way instead of building whole JSON by JS.

Comment: Then above answer should work fine, and instead of having multiple scenarios, you can have a scenario Outline with index of rules in your examples.

Comment: @PeterThomas - Should I raise enhancement request for remove to allow multiple indices in a json ?

Comment: @SourabhChapali I disagree. why don't you go the other way and use `set` to add the rules you need. also I honestly haven't understood your need because it doesn't follow the MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Just thought , The way we can set whatever we want flawlessly . We should also be able to remove whatever we want from json :)

Comment: @SourabhChapali feel free to do what you want, I will insist on a MCVE

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#{
#"RULE": {
#  "operator": "EQUALS_LT",
#  "attribute_name": "CHECKOUT",
#  "attribute_value": "16 Nov 2018",
#  "attribute_value_type": "DATE",
#  "status": "ACTIVE"
#}
#}
Scenario:
* def data = { op: 'EQUALS_LT' }
* set rule1
| path | 0 | 1 |
| RULE.operator | data.op | 'AND' |
| RULE.attribute_name | (null) | 'bbb' |
| RULE.attribute_valule | '16 Nov 2018' | 'ggg' |
| RULE.attribute_value_type | 'DATE' | 'ddd' |
| RULE.status | 'ACTIVE' | 'jjj' |

* print rule1
* set rule2
| path | 0 | 1 |
| RULE.operator | data.op | rule1 |
| RULE.attribute_name | (null) | 'bbb' |
| RULE.attribute_valule | '16 Nov 2018' | 'ggg' |
| RULE.attribute_value_type | 'DATE' | 'ddd' |
| RULE.status | 'ACTIVE' | 'jjj' |

* print rule2
```